# Update not happening with Spring Data JPA

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I'm using programmatic configuration of Spring Data JPA which goes like this:

```
package com.bosch.bip.Utils;


import java.util.Properties;

import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.QueryLookupStrategy.Key;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages="com.bosch.bip.Repositories",queryLookupStrategy=Key.CREATE_IF_NOT_FOUND)
public class PersistentContext {




    @Bean
    DataSource datasource()
    {
        BasicDataSource ds=new BasicDataSource();
        ds.setUrl("jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.165.18.29:1521:ORCL");
        ds.setDriverClassName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        ds.setUsername("BIPUser");
        ds.setPassword("BIP");

        return ds;
    }

    @Bean
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(DataSource ds)
    {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean emf= new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        emf.setDataSource(ds);
        emf.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());
        emf.setPackagesToScan("com.bosch.bip.Entities");


        Properties jpaProperties = new Properties();
        jpaProperties.put("hibernate.dialect","org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect");
        jpaProperties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");
        jpaProperties.put("hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans", "true");
        jpaProperties.put("hibernate.format_sql", "true");
        jpaProperties.put("hibernate.show_sql", "true");

        emf.setJpaProperties(jpaProperties);

        return emf;

    }

    @Bean
    JpaTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory emf)
    {
        JpaTransactionManager tm= new JpaTransactionManager();
        tm.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);    
        return tm;
    }
}
```

And I'm using a custom repository to update a row in my DB, the code of which goes like this:

```
package com.bosch.bip.Repositories;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Modifying;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.bosch.bip.Entities.AdapterVersion;


public interface AdapterVersion_REP  extends JpaRepository<AdapterVersion, Long>{


    @Modifying(clearAutomatically=true)
    @Query(value ="update ADAPTER_VERSION av SET av.DESCRIPTION=:description WHERE av.ADAPTER_ID=:adapterId AND av.VERSION=:version",nativeQuery=true )
    @Transactional
    int updateSelectedAdapterDetails(@Param("description") String description,@Param("adapterId") int adapterId, @Param("version") String serverVersion );

}
```

When I try executing the query using a REST client, the console just goes blank without any action.
Please help as I'm unable to get through this.

Logs for the SQL:

```
May 11, 2016 1:31:32 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'antiJARLocking' to 'true' did not find a matching property.
May 11, 2016 1:31:32 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:activiti-explorer' did not find a matching property.
May 11, 2016 1:31:32 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.0.30
May 11, 2016 1:31:32 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server built:          Dec 1 2015 22:30:46 UTC
May 11, 2016 1:31:32 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server number:         8.0.30.0
May 11, 2016 1:31:32 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Name:               Windows 7
May 11, 2016 1:31:32 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Version:            6.1
May 11, 2016 1:31:32 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Architecture:          amd64
May 11, 2016 1:31:32 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jre8
May 11, 2016 1:31:32 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Version:           1.8.0_71-b15
May 11, 2016 1:31:32 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
May 11, 2016 1:31:32 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_BASE:         C:\Himangshu\WS\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
May 11, 2016 1:31:32 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_HOME:         C:\Users\CHH7KOR\Desktop\apache-tomcat-8.0.30
May 11, 2016 1:31:32 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,suspend=y,address=localhost:5858
May 11, 2016 1:31:32 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\Himangshu\WS\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
May 11, 2016 1:31:32 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\Users\CHH7KOR\Desktop\apache-tomcat-8.0.30
May 11, 2016 1:31:32 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=C:\Himangshu\WS\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps
May 11, 2016 1:31:32 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\Users\CHH7KOR\Desktop\apache-tomcat-8.0.30\endorsed
May 11, 2016 1:31:32 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252
May 11, 2016 1:31:32 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre8\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_74/bin/../jre/bin/server;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_74/bin/../jre/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_74/bin/../jre/lib/amd64;C:\Users\CHH7KOR\Documents\Maven\apache-maven-3.3.9\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_74\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Maven\apache-maven-3.3.9\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\7-Zip;C:\Program Files (x86)\Toolbase Client;C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Fabric 1.5 & MySQL Utilities 1.5\;C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Fabric 1.5 & MySQL Utilities 1.5\Doctrine extensions for PHP\;C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem;C:\Program Files (x86)\Ant\apache-ant-1.9.6-bin\apache-ant-1.9.6\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\WebEx\Productivity Tools;C:\Users\CHH7KOR\Downloads\eclipse;;C:\Program Files\WinMagic\SecureDoc-NT\;.
May 11, 2016 1:31:32 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
May 11, 2016 1:31:33 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
May 11, 2016 1:31:33 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
May 11, 2016 1:31:33 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
May 11, 2016 1:31:33 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 1387 ms
May 11, 2016 1:31:33 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
May 11, 2016 1:31:33 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.30
May 11, 2016 1:31:33 PM org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGeneratorBase createSecureRandom
INFO: Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [151] milliseconds.
May 11, 2016 1:31:41 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
May 11, 2016 1:31:41 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Spring WebApplicationInitializers detected on classpath: [com.bosch.bip.RESTfulServices.RESTfulInitializer@1e936f98]
May 11, 2016 1:31:41 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
01:31:41,738 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader  - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
01:31:41,929 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext  - Refreshing Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Wed May 11 13:31:41 IST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
01:31:42,067 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext  - Registering annotated classes: [class com.bosch.bip.RESTfulServices.RESTfulConfiguration]
01:31:43,187 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping  - Mapped "{[/adapters/update],methods=[POST],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.lang.Object> com.bosch.bip.RESTfulServices.AdapterController_CRUD.createUser(org.springframework.util.MultiValueMap<java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object>)
01:31:43,187 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping  - Mapped "{[/adapters/allAdapterDetails],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.util.List<java.lang.Object> com.bosch.bip.RESTfulServices.AdapterController_CRUD.serviceForFetchingAllAdapterDetails() throws java.io.IOException
01:31:43,188 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping  - Mapped "{[/adapters/selectedAdapterDetailsForUpdate/{adapterId}/{serverVersion}],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.util.List<java.lang.Object> com.bosch.bip.RESTfulServices.AdapterController_CRUD.serviceForFetchingSelectedAdapterDetails(java.util.Map<java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object>) throws java.io.IOException
01:31:43,875 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter  - Looking for @ControllerAdvice: Root WebApplicationContext: startup date [Wed May 11 13:31:41 IST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
01:31:44,072 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader  - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2332 ms
01:31:44,083 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet  - FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher': initialization started
May 11, 2016 1:31:44 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher'
01:31:44,148 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet  - FrameworkServlet 'dispatcher': initialization completed in 65 ms
May 11, 2016 1:31:44 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
May 11, 2016 1:31:44 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
May 11, 2016 1:31:44 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 11078 ms
01:31:52,099 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] INFO  org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext  - Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@12b5782d: startup date [Wed May 11 13:31:52 IST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
01:31:56,158 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] INFO  org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean  - Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
01:31:56,416 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] INFO  org.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  - HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    ...]
01:31:57,686 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] INFO  org.hibernate.Version  - HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.11.Final}
01:31:57,725 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] INFO  org.hibernate.cfg.Environment  - HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
01:31:57,738 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] INFO  org.hibernate.cfg.Environment  - HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
01:32:00,394 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] INFO  org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version  - HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.5.Final}
01:32:02,658 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] INFO  org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect  - HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
01:32:02,790 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] INFO  org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LobCreatorBuilder  - HHH000424: Disabling contextual LOB creation as createClob() method threw error : java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
01:32:04,883 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] INFO  org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory  - HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
01:32:09,570 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] INFO  org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate  - HHH000228: Running hbm2ddl schema update
01:32:09,571 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] INFO  org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate  - HHH000102: Fetching database metadata
01:32:09,860 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] INFO  org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate  - HHH000396: Updating schema
01:32:10,679 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] INFO  org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata  - HHH000261: Table found: BIPUSER.ADAPTER
01:32:10,679 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] INFO  org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata  - HHH000037: Columns: [name, id, is_client, classification]
01:32:10,680 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] INFO  org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata  - HHH000108: Foreign keys: []
01:32:10,681 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] INFO  org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata  - HHH000126: Indexes: [adapter_pk]
01:32:10,746 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] INFO  org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata  - HHH000261: Table found: BIPUSER.ADAPTER_SERVER_MAP
01:32:10,747 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] INFO  org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata  - HHH000037: Columns: [adapter_version_id, server_id]
01:32:10,748 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] INFO  org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata  - HHH000108: Foreign keys: [adapter_server_map_server_fk, adapter_server_map_adapver_fk]
01:32:10,748 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] INFO  org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata  - HHH000126: Indexes: []
01:32:10,817 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] INFO  org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata  - HHH000261: Table found: BIPUSER.ADAPTER_VERSION
01:32:10,817 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] INFO  org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata  - HHH000037: Columns: [num_recon_attempt, polling_freq, tooltip, jar_path, description, adapter_id, id, category, type, version, status]
01:32:10,818 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] INFO  org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata  - HHH000108: Foreign keys: [adapter_version_configval_fkv1, adapter_version_adapter_fk]
01:32:10,819 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] INFO  org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata  - HHH000126: Indexes: [adapter_version_pk]
01:32:10,868 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] INFO  org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata  - HHH000261: Table found: BIPUSER.CONFIG_TYPE
01:32:10,868 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] INFO  org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata  - HHH000037: Columns: [id, type, value]
01:32:10,869 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] INFO  org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata  - HHH000108: Foreign keys: []
01:32:10,870 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] INFO  org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata  - HHH000126: Indexes: [configuration_pk]
01:32:10,911 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] INFO  org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata  - HHH000261: Table found: BIPUSER.CONFIG_VALUE
01:32:10,911 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] INFO  org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata  - HHH000037: Columns: [config_value, id, config_type]
01:32:10,912 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] INFO  org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata  - HHH000108: Foreign keys: [config_value_config_type_fk]
01:32:10,913 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] INFO  org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata  - HHH000126: Indexes: [config_value_pk]
01:32:10,956 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] INFO  org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata  - HHH000261: Table found: BIPUSER.FEATURE
01:32:10,956 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] INFO  org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata  - HHH000037: Columns: [feature, id]
01:32:10,957 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] INFO  org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata  - HHH000108: Foreign keys: []
01:32:10,957 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] INFO  org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata  - HHH000126: Indexes: [feature_pk]
01:32:11,003 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] INFO  org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata  - HHH000261: Table found: BIPUSER.SERVER
01:32:11,003 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] INFO  org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata  - HHH000037: Columns: [server, id, server_version]
01:32:11,004 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] INFO  org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata  - HHH000108: Foreign keys: [server_adapter_fk]
01:32:11,004 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] INFO  org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata  - HHH000126: Indexes: [server_pk]
01:32:11,049 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] INFO  org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata  - HHH000261: Table found: BIPUSER.SERVICE_ORCHESTRATION
01:32:11,049 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] INFO  org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata  - HHH000037: Columns: [orchestration_value, orchestration_name, id]
01:32:11,050 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] INFO  org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata  - HHH000108: Foreign keys: []
01:32:11,051 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] INFO  org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata  - HHH000126: Indexes: [service_orchestration_pk]
01:32:11,092 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] INFO  org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata  - HHH000261: Table found: BIPUSER.TEMPLATE
01:32:11,092 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] INFO  org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata  - HHH000037: Columns: [feature_id, template, id, language_id]
01:32:11,093 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] INFO  org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata  - HHH000108: Foreign keys: [template_language_fk, template_feature_fk]
01:32:11,094 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] INFO  org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata  - HHH000126: Indexes: [template_pk]
01:32:11,201 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] INFO  org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata  - HHH000261: Table found: BIPUSER.LANGUAGE
01:32:11,201 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] INFO  org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata  - HHH000037: Columns: [language, id]
01:32:11,202 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] INFO  org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata  - HHH000108: Foreign keys: []
01:32:11,203 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] INFO  org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata  - HHH000126: Indexes: [language_pk]
01:32:11,216 [http-nio-8080-exec-2] INFO  org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate  - HHH000232: Schema update complete
hadfaj3
Hibernate: 
    update
        ADAPTER_VERSION av 
    SET
        av.DESCRIPTION=? 
    WHERE
        av.ADAPTER_ID=? 
        AND av.VERSION=?
```

Comment: Can you see that SQL is issued to the DB in log files? Set log level for hibernate <logger name="org.hibernate.SQL" level="DEBUG"/> and look through the logs to find out whether the SQL was sent to DB.

Comment: @inigoskimmer I did that and I guess the query is being hit.Please see the logs in the edited question

Comment: As query is sent to DB may be there are not rows matching the WHERE cause in update statement. What is the result (number of rows updated) of updateSelectedAdapterDetails invocation?

Answer (score 1):

Can you please change it to the below and try:

```
@Modifying(clearAutomatically=true)
@Query(value ="update ADAPTER_VERSION av SET av.DESCRIPTION=:description WHERE av.ADAPTER_ID=:adapterId AND av.VERSION=:version",nativeQuery=true )
void updateSelectedAdapterDetails(@Param("description") String description,@Param("adapterId") int adapterId, @Param("version") String serverVersion );
```

Move the transactional to the service/component making a call to the update function.